# A problem with finding cdf of a mixed variable

Tags: statistics

I need to find cdf of random variable Y

$
Y=g(x)=
\begin{cases}
3, & \text{X<3} \\
X, & 3 \le X \le 5 \\
5, & \text{X>5}
\end{cases}
$

Y is a mixed variable. 
X is a continous random variable with uniform distribution on [2;7]. I need to find cdf of Y.

My solution:

$3 \le g(x) \le 5$

$
X=
\begin{cases}
\frac15 & 2\le X\le 7 \\
0, & otherwise \\
\end{cases}
$

P(Y=3)=P(X<3)=$\int_{2}^{3} \frac 15 = \frac 15 $

P(Y=5)=P(X>5)=$\frac 25$

3< y <5: $F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X\le y)=\int_{3}^{y} \frac 15=\frac 15 y-\frac 35$

Also,

$
F_Y(y)=0  ~for ~y<3  \\
F_Y(y)=1 ~for  ~y>5
$

The problem is, that for y=3 I got $\frac 15$
but for $3<y<5$ the value is $0$ ($\frac 15 y - \frac 35 =0 ~for~y=3)$ and it's not right.
Where did I make a mistake?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for $3<y<5$ 
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y \leq y)=P(Y=3)+P(3<Y\leq y) =\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5}(y-3) $$